# How to return object of class array from Java to JNI?

Tags: android, native

I am trying to make one app based on native library. and I need to do java method call in jni but jni give run time error.

Java method Code:here is Texture is java class.

```
private Texture[] getProductTexture() {
    return mBookDataTexture;
}
```

Jni Code

```
getProductTextureID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "getProductTexture", "()[Lcom/qualcomm/QCARSamples/CloudRecognition/Texture;");
jobjectArray  textureObjectArray =(jobjectArray) env->CallObjectMethod(activityObj, getProductTextureID);
jsize length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jobjectArray);
for(jint i=0; i<length;i++){
    jobject = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, textureObjectArray , i);
}
```